# Function call ioctl with VIDIOC_QUERYCAP request doesn't return

Tags: v4l2

I write a program to capture video from /dev/video0.
(Opening with VLC is OK).
I use v4l2 api ( in http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html)

When init device, function call **ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap)** doesn't return, it blocks my program.

```
if (-1 == xioctl (fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &cap))
{
    if (EINVAL == errno)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s is no V4L2 device\n", dev_name);
        opened = false;
        return false;
    } else
    {
        return errno_exit("VIDIOC_QUERYCAP");
    }
}
```

I must kill the process. After, I open /dev/video0 in VLC again, VLC can't play video until I restart my PC.

How can I set timeout for ioctl ? Thanks !

Comment: can you run `v4l2-ctl --all` on the device? (if the device is not `/dev/video0` use the `-d` option)

Comment: Thanks ! I run above command, output :  Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
        Driver name   : tw68
        Card type     : GENERIC
        Bus info      : PCI:0000:04:04.0
        Driver version: 0.0.8
        Capabilities  : 0x05000011
                Video Capture
                VBI Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming

Comment: please add that info to the question